# Squarefree binomial coefficients.

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

At $n=23$, all binomial coefficients are squarefree. Is this the largest value for $n$ where this is the case?

## Edit

A plot up to $n=50$:

[image]

A plot up to $n=500$:

[image]

plotted against $n+1$ and $\frac{112}{\sqrt{239}}\sqrt{n}$

and the same up to $n=2000$:

[image]

Do these bounds hold for all $n$?

*(Clearly, the bound $n+1$ holds for all $n$.)*

## Update

Just out of interest, a plot up to $n=2000$ with bounding curve $24\log(n)$

($24\approx\frac{148}{\log 479}$, where $148$ is the number of squarefree binomial coefficients at $n=479$),

which seems to be the tightest curve which still holds for up to $n=3967$:

[image]

... seems to suggest that the bound is $const. \log(n)$, which so far shows $c\approx24$ (which, coincidentally, is the number of squarefree coefficients at $n=23$).

Comment: I checked numerically up to $n=10^5$, and $23$ is still the largest.

Comment: How did you check up till there? Did you use a program?

Comment: Yes. In [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/): `Filtered([1..100000], n -> ForAll([0..n], k -> MoebiusMu(Binomial(n,k))<>0));`

Comment: Actually, it's the last, see [OEIS sequence A048278](http://oeis.org/A048278)

Comment: @arbautjc Sorry for converting to an answer. I thought you would yourself but it's been almost 15 minutes. Sorry again. Let me know if you want me to delete mine.

Comment: No problem with that, I upvote! :-)

Comment: @arbautjc Thank you so much!  $\mathrm{}\\$

Comment: Your plots are interesting. Is it the number of sqfree binomials? The curve suggest a pike in log(n) or $\sqrt{n}$, now it would be nice to know for which $n$ the pikes appear, and deduce some rule... well, just dreaming :-)

Comment: @ arbautjc, thanks for the link. My thanks are referred on from Ahaan Rungta ;)

Comment: Yes - they are plots of the squarefree binomials. I agree - it would be nice to know!

Comment: In case one is interested, the next "record" value after n=479 (148 binomials are square free) is for n=3967 (182 square free). Checked up to 4500.

Comment: Thanks for checking - just running a plot now :)

Comment: _Mathematica_ doesn't like it. The bound $\frac{148 \log(n)}{\log 479}$ seems to be the tightest that still holds for $n=3967$ though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See **[here](http://oeis.org/A048278)**. The $n=23$ case is the last.

Comment: @ Ahaan Rungta - many thanks for your link :)

Comment: Actually, it's arbautjc's credit. See his comment.