# Bound for squarefree binomial coefficients

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Numerical tests up to $x=2000$ seem to suggest that the number of squarefree binomial coefficients is bounded at $\dfrac{112x^{\ y}}{239^{\ y}}$:

[image]

where

$y={\frac{\text{log}\left(\frac{148}{112}\right)}{\text{log}\left(\frac{479}{239}\right)}}$

(where the number of squarefree binomial coefficients is $112$ at $239$, and $148$ at $479$.)

My questions are:

(a) Does this bound hold for all n?

and *(a bit more far-fetched!)*

(b) Does the number of squarefree binomial coefficients reach a maximum?

## Update

Plot up to $n=1000$ showing two different bounding curves:

[image]

Comment: For reference: this is a continuation of [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584748/squarefree-binomial-coefficients).

Comment: There are 182 squarefree binomial coefficients at 3967.

Comment: Great! Thanks for checking :)

Comment: So I am guessing the answer is yes for (a) & no for (b)?

Comment: ... Or is (a) too small a bound?

Comment: ... Would a better bound be $\frac{148 \log(x)}{\log 479}$ ?